# Converting column in data frame to class list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to convert a column in data frame into a list.

The data frame is in this format

```
State   combo
1   0,0,0,0,0,0
2   1,0,0,0,0,0
3   0,1,0,0,0,0
4   1,1,0,0,0,0
5   0,0,1,0,0,0
6   1,0,1,0,0,0
7   0,1,1,0,0,0
```

What I need to do is change each row in the column 'combo' to a numeric list. So what I want to end up with is something where row 1 is equal to `c(0,0,0,0,0)` etc.

my code so far is...

```
list.combo<- read.csv("data")

rownames(list.combo) <- list.char$State

char.l <- list.char%>%
  select(combo)
```

Comment: is `combo` column comma separated strings ? Can you update your post with `dput(list.combo)` ?

Comment: currently it is a class = factor

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but is `df$combo <- strsplit(as.character(df$combo), ",")` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way with `tidyverse` -

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(combo, sep = ",") %>% 
  {split(as.numeric(.$combo), .$State)} %>% 
  setNames(paste0("State", seq_along(.)))

$State1
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$State2
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0

$State3
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0

$State4
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 0

$State5
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0

$State6
[1] 1 0 1 0 0 0

$State7
[1] 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Here's a better way derived from @thelatemail comment -

```
strsplit(as.character(df$combo), ",") %>% 
  lapply(as.numeric) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("State", seq_along(.)))
```

Data -

```
df <- read.table(text = "State   combo
1   0,0,0,0,0,0
2   1,0,0,0,0,0
3   0,1,0,0,0,0
4   1,1,0,0,0,0
5   0,0,1,0,0,0
6   1,0,1,0,0,0
7   0,1,1,0,0,0", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: No problem. See if thelatemail's solution in comments works for you. It's better if it does.